# Is it a bad idea to let a css background-image url point to a non-image file?

Tags: css, image, http, background

I want to do something hackish in order to have responsive images generated automatically with js & php. I would like to do this with my css `background-image: url(#/path/to/image.jpg)`, so that I can specify various image paths that javascript can grab but which won't actually result in separate HTTP requests.

The browser interprets the above code as http://example.com/cssfolder/#/path/to/image.jpg. Which means it is just pointing to the css folder. In my brief tests, if there is an index file in the folder the Chrome console will complain "Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html" but if there is no index it will give a 404 message.

So that feels kind of bad, but it doesn't seem to affect the browsing experience. I guess developers may not like this method since it pollutes the console with errors, but is there an objective reason to avoid this? Are there some browsers that would actually mess up the page, bearing in mind that a real background image would be immediately supplied with javascript?

Comment: if you are supplying the real background image with JS, why not set the attribute via JS as well and forget about setting it in the CSS?

Comment: Because that would be really lame. CSS is the place where you are supposed to define your styles, not in JS. The JS would just be a file you include in your HTML that automatically delivers the right sized image based on the full res image specified in the css.

Comment: I can see you are doing something hackish (your words) to have responsive images but are unwilling to leave the CSS alone (and create additional browser requests that only return a 404) - yet you are calling my suggestion lame? (even when it is slightly better?) - The objective reason to avoid it is that you are creating additional requests to the browser (for each image, I don't know how many) that are never going to get resolved so both the server and browser have to deal with a bunch of 404s (not just devs) - the more images you have, the bigger I/O, the worse the performance on your site.

Comment: But no matter how many images there are on a page there will only ever be one such 404. How bad is a 404? And there are ways to avoid it, such as `url(/img/placeholder.gif#img/real.jpg)`, but I would like to get away without that if it's OK.